# Adfonic Full Ad in Android blank screen

Tags: android, ads

Using last Adfonic Sdk, and the Android guide : http://developer.adfonic.com/index.php/Android_SDK

I have created two slots for my app (at http://adfonic.com/sites-and-apps/ad-integration) a normal Text Link Banner and a Full Ad.

When I test in the simple case following the guide, I get the simple banner on screen but not the full banner.

My code is like follows:

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <com.adfonic.android.AdfonicView
       xmlns:adfonic="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.adfonic.android"
       android:id="@+id/adfonicView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       adfonic:adfonic_adslot_id="AD_SLOT_ID"
       adfonic:language="en"
       adfonic:refresh_ad="true"
       adfonic:refresh_time="30" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String TAG = "Testing";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdfonicView adView = (AdfonicView) findViewById(R.id.adfonicView);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedAd() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onReceivedAd()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPresentScreen() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onPresentScreen()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNoFill() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onNoFill()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onNetworkError()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onLeaveApplication() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onLeaveApplication()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidRequest() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onInvalidRequest()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInternalError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onInternalError()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onDismissScreen() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onDismissScreen()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onClick()");

        }
    });
}}
```

In Log, I get with normal banner the callbacks "onReceivedAd()" and "onPresentScreen()" are fired, but when full screen ad, only "onReceivedAd()" is been called. And the white screen remains.

The responses for banner requests, are shown in Log too, and in both cases are correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a need to place a:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedAd() {

adView.showInterstitial(); // <—show the ad
}
```

As the ad is interstitial and goes full screen, there is a need to force
the display.

Let me know if this works for you.